# rotation os shape in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I want to rotate my shape in both clockwise and anti clockwise depending on the direction in which I move my mouse.Here is the sample kinda I know not exactly perfect..if possible edit my offset and the rotating part. Here is the `fiddle`

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rotation by doing something like: (mix of pseudo-code and actual code)

```
  var currentRotation = shape.getRotation();
  var direction = ..stuff.. ; // your logic for mouse movement, result should be 1 or -1
  var rotationAmount = 0.5; 

  shape.setRotation(currentRotation + direction * rotationAmount); //get current rotation and add/subtract some arbitrary amount
```

If you need an offset, you can do:

```
  shape.setOffset(x,y);
```